# Two title bars on UIViewController (subview of UITableViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

So I have a table view controller that shows pictures then when you select a cell it opens a UIViewController with an image view and a navigation bar with buttons to go back or to save the image. The problem is that I'm getting a second title bar. I can't seem to remove it, I can't change the text, and to be honest I can't seem to find where it's coming from. When I select it it selects the navigation bar but if I delete or hide the navigation bar it hides the bar with the buttons and this "Title" bar stays.

Here's what it looks like running in the simulator:

[image: titleBarIssue]

Any ideas on how I can get rid of this thing or at least change it's title? The only thing that seems to change it is when I load a very small image it will expand to fill the remaining view space like so:

[image: largeTitleBar]

I've deleted the UIImageView and even the view in the nib and it's still there. I've even deleted the nib itself and nothing changes. I can only guess that the superview is loading it somehow but I can't find anything in there that could cause it. If it were coming from the cell method it would have the title of the image and not just "title."

Here's the code from the Superview (which is a table view controller) that initializes the screen with the problem:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *title = [completePicturesList objectAtIndex:row];
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory, title];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

GCDetailViewController *childController = [[GCDetailViewController alloc] init];
childController.mainImage = image;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
```

}

and here's the viewWillAppear of the UIViewController that's showing the duplicate:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

mainImageDisplay.image = mainImage;

UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveImageToPhotoAlbum)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
NSString *titleText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image Review"];
self.title = titleText;
```

The only other methods in this class are for saving the photo. Also, no nib is assigned to this either so it's not there. As for self.title, well if I change that it changes the text that says "Image Review" NOT the "title" below it. If I try to hide the navigation bar it hides the image review bar and the title bar stays.

Just for fun here's the cellForRow method to see if maybe it's something in there:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *cellTitle = [completePicturesList objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory, cellTitle];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

cell.textLabel.text = cellTitle;
cell.imageView.image = image;

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Are you building this out from a nib? Sounds like it's present on the nib file but is not hooked up to anything in your code.

Comment: That's what I thought too and I did use a nib in the storyboard and connect it to the UIViewController class but the navigation bar in the nib is the top bar, the bottom bar is not visible anywhere on the nib.

Comment: Edit: I have deleted the nib attached to the view controller that has the problem and its still there.

Comment: How are you setting up this view controller? Is it subclassing another UIViewController that could be adding the title bar? Could you post the interface declaration in the header file? Is it possible to post some code from the viewDidLoad and init methods on the implementation file as well? This problem does not look to be too bad. Short of providing access to your project (which, of course, I am not expecting), the best that you can do is provide as much information and code that you can :)

Comment: The controller that's having the problem isn't subclassed from anything but UIViewController. I've completely deleted the nib that I had assigned to it from the storyboard. I've posted the didselectrow from the superview (UITableViewController) and the viewDidAppear from the UIViewController that's showing both bars.

Comment: Hmm weird. Ok this is a silly thing to suggest but I've read somewhere about nibs being cached so try cleaning your project and rebuild to see if that changes anything. Meanwhile, are you online right now so we could move this discussion over to chat?

Comment: I am, what format do you prefer? BTW, the clean and rebuild didn't work.

Comment: Well you cant chat with a rep of 11. I upvoted two of your questions so that should enable you to chat. You don't seem to be online though. I will be online at 10 pm Pacific Time tonight. Let's crack this problem then :)

Comment: I've got to be at work tomorrow at 8 and I'm on the east coast so I won't be up. Thanks a ton for the offer though man. I've tried a few more things and the only think I can get to work (and I wouldn't call it working) is that if I make the navigation bar a translucent black it hides that ugly "title" bar behind itself. It's not elegant and I don't plan on it being permanent but perhaps it could be a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please excuse me if it's not OK to answer my own question but I did find the solution.

The title bar came from an old nib. I made it in the storyboard, added the bar, then changed my mind on how I wanted to approach it and deleted it.

For whatever reason when I was reloading the app, both on the simulator and on my phone, it wasn't overwriting the old nib that originally caused this problem (even though it was deleted from xCode). I simply deleted the app from the phone and simulator and reloaded it and the title bar was gone.